# Why does NumberStyles.Any not allow the percent symbol?

Tags: .net

When parsing as a decimal, you may very well want to parse a number like "23.393%", but this doesn't work without manually stripping off the percent symbol (`%`). I would expect this line to return true:

```cs
Decimal.TryParse("31.7%",System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, null, out var dec)
```

The documentation for [System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_NumberStyles_Any) seems to indicate that it should allow any sort of (decimal) number formatting. Is there a reason Percent wasn't included?

> (note: I'm working in C#, but the underlying TryParse function should also be in VB.NET and other .NET languages, so this question applies to them too)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mis-reading that document. The note for `Any` says this:

> all styles except AllowHexSpecifier are used. This is a composite number style.

This doesn't mean anything goes. It only means any of the other **specific** entries in the `NumberStyles` enum work (except, of course, `AllowHexSpecifier`). ***None*** of those number styles have anything to do with the percent sign or your format here. The closest is `AllowTrailingSign`, but reading the note for that style we see this:

> Valid trailing sign characters are determined by the PositiveSign and NegativeSign properties.

No percent option there. Looks like you're gonna have to manage this format yourself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Note that the original question was **why** the percent sign was not included. Are they only going for currencies (clearly not, because of hex options)?